# How to send special characters using tcp/ip sockets?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to build my first client/server apps and to exchange data between them using sockets.

When I try to send "%" character for example or "_", I'm getting on the other side a "\0".

How to send special characters using tcp/ip sockets in C++ ?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Don't you have any code to provide ?

Comment: @Lucie kulza  There is nothing special to send a special character.. You can send as normal way

Comment: @Vinoth, I've tried to send "%" lso a "_" but I'm getting "\0" on the other side.

Comment: can you able to receive the normal character

Comment: @Vinoth, yes I'm able to receive alphanumeric characters, ":" and "/".

Comment: There's nothing special about sending those characters. Set a breakpoint in your code and check the buffer that you're transmitting. There's probably something in your code that preps the characters for transmission.

Comment: @Luciekulza Its highly better if u share the code

Comment: TCP sockets just send a series of raw bytes, verbatim.  They neither know nor care what those bytes represent; all 256 possible byte values will be handled the exact same way by the TCP layer.  So if you are seeing behavior that is specific to certain byte values, the problem is almost certainly elsewhere in your code.

Comment: C++ does not define any socket API. So you must use other functions like the Berkely socket API. Please provide the code that you use with that API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that "%" is a string and not a character. In C/C++, this means that you're silently also getting a string termination. Try using '%'.

Comment: I'm trying to send a whole string which have this form `ABCDDSK%sqdoljDQSJL`, when I get this string from the other side I get `ABCDDSK\0sqdoljDQSJL`

Comment: Okay, we then need some code and some more information. Is it Linux, Windows, OSX, what library do you use, ...?

Comment: Thaks for your response, the problem was from the server, I was using a bad function.